# How to properly display a grid in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an app that displays popular movies right now. It uses TMDB API to fetch this data. I'm using RecyclerView which displays clickable ImageViews in a grid consisting 2 columns.
This is the result I want to achieve:
[an edge to edge grid of all movies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpLpm.jpg) that I can only achieve by hard coding values:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">`

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="185dp" <!--HARDCODED VALUES-->
        android:layout_height="278dp"<!--HARDCODED VALUES-->
        android:contentDescription="@string/movie"
        android:id="@+id/rv_image_view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I use `layout_width="match_parent"` or `layout_height="wrap_content"` I get extremely weird and skewed results. [Like this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZKQD.jpg) How should I fix this?
Please don't mark this as duplicate. I've searched far and wide for this and came up with absolutely nothing.

Comment: you can refer https://github.com/rahulpandey/MovieDB/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rahul/movie/db/view/RectangleImageView.java this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this create a layout file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/movies_item"
    android:layout_width="185dp" 
    android:layout_height="278dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In activity :

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/movies_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: follow this if you still have doubts